# UserControl get set Property in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, textbox, get

I am getting an error like

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ciscontrols.dll".

My code is given below

```
    private int _vin;

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get { return _vin; }

        set //Here your answer solve the promblem
        {
            txtLocl.MaxLength = value;
            if (value < 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MaxLength","MaxLength MinValue should be 2.");
            }
            else this._vin = value;
        }
    }
```

i am creating a new property for decimal places

```
private int Dval;
    public int DecPlaces
    {
        get { return Dval; }
        set// here it showing the same error
        {
            DecPlaces = value; // MaxLength is a preDefined Property but  DecPlaces created by me.
            if (value < 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("decplaces", "decimal places minimum value should be 2.");
            }
            else this.Dval = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your property's setter is calling itself on this line:

```
 this.MaxLength = value;
```

Change it to:

```
set //Here i am getting Error
{
    txtLocl.MaxLength = value;
    if (value < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("MaxLength","MaxLength MinValue should be 2.");
    }
    else this._vin = value;
}
```

For this particular exception, the Call Stack window displayed in Visual Studio while debugging is helpful in seeing which methods are calling each other in an infinite loop. The setter of a property eventually becomes a method called set_MaxLength in the run-time.

Comment: You are again creating an infinite loop in the new code when the setter says DecPlaces =value. This causes the setter to call itself again. Change it to Dval =value or change it to set the value of a control like you did in yhe first example. Setters should set fields not themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Your setter is recursive because you have

```
this.MaxLength = value;
```

Within your setter. This will result in an infinite loop, and eventually, a `StackOverflowException`.

Use

```
this._vin = value;
```

Instead

Answer (score 1):

```
this.MaxLength = value
```

This line triggers an infinite loop, because it calls the `set` accessor that you are already in. Did you mean to set the value of a backing variable instead?